# Get AppStore URL programming

Tags: ios, app-store, app-id

I want to share my application via Facebook by using `UIActivityViewController`

How can I get AppStore URL programing ?

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow, please read how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also check [How to Ask Good Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so you increase your chances to get feedback and useful answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For that you need to create an app profile in [itunesConnect](https://itunesconnect.apple.com/). There you will get the link to your app page from the **app information** section. You can use the link used in **View in app store** button in that page. That link will go to the page in which your app will be visible to the users after uploading

Right click on view in app store -> copy link address -> Share the link in `UIActivityViewController`

[image]

Comment: This link is not available anymore

Answer (score 1):

search for your App in Itunes.Along with GET there is a drop down,click it and select COPY link to get link of your App.
Keep it static in text message to be shared by activityViewController.

[image]